# Parsing string to extract XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Lets say I have the following String:

```
abc: def
qxy
<?xml version='1.0'><xyz>
...
</xyz>
other text
<?xml version='1.0'><www>
...
</www>
more text
```

Is there a way to parse this?  I am currently trying with an XMLStreamReader and it throws a parsing error: `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError`.  If I remove all the test and just try to parse one of the XML sections (like only xyz) then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to filter out the xml part. No general purpose XMLStreamReader will do it for you since they have no idea where your document starts or ends. You may craft your own specialized version that can filter the input, but other implementations expect a full xml document only.

Comment: oh, so XML parsers can find text within a document, but are not able to find text outside the document?  I was suspecting this is the case, but are there no other XML parsers other than XMLStreamReader that will do this for me?

Comment: An XML document has to be well formed to be parsed by an XML parser correctly. This means there is only one root element, no content outside the root element and tags have to be balanced. You should first extract the XML documents before you can parse them.